# How do I reset an Activesync ABQ for a device? (make the policy block it by default)

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

I thought the approval of an approved activesync device was stored in the Activesync partnerships commandlet, however I just removed all partnerships for a given user and there was no ABQ policy applied to the device.

- If I approve an Activesync device, where is that "approval" saved?
- How do I reset the ABQ setting for a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this

```
Get-CASMailbox "mailboxuser" | Select  ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs, ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs)
```

If the results show DeviceIDs still in the list then run:

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity "mailboxuser" -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs:""
```

This will remove all devices in the allowed list for that mailbox.  Then any new device should act like new and get whatever ABQ is appropriate on "first sync".  If you have any in the Blocked list you'll need to run the 2nd command as well for the `-ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs:""`

Make sure you run this only on the mailbox in question...or you'll remove everyone's currently allowed DeviceIDs!